# unix date conversion in tizen

Tags: c++, date, tizen

I have a 13 digit integer like (1384318800000) which is said to be unix format. I need this date in MM/DD/YYYY . There is no visual match in this (`1384318800000`) points to a date `11/13/2013` . Let me know if any one knows this conversion

Comment: The number you have is too large.  Now, if you lop off a few zeroes to get `1384318800` then that is Wed, 13 Nov 2013 05:00:00 GMT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With given time_t value (which is 1384318800000 in your case) you can initialise tm structure using [localtime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/) function and then format a string using [strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/)

Comment: how to initialise the time with 1384318800000

Comment: `#include <ctime>`

`time_t given_time = 1384318800000;`

Comment: I dont have a header <ctime> just <time.h>

Comment: @Arju: That's the C header. Are you writing C or C++?

Comment: You'll also need to divide by 1000 to get a Posix `time_t` (measured in seconds), since this value is measured in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an epoch converter. If you google epoch time converter you can find some helpful resources. http://www.epochconverter.com/ is a website devoted to this, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The value you've specified was given in Unix time in milliseconds. The `strftime` deals with epoch time which is specified in seconds format. You will have to divide the value with 1000 before you feed to `time_t` variable. After all time_t is defined as long.

```
time_t t = 1384245237000/1000;
char       buf[80];
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", localtime(&t));
printf("%s\n", buf);
```